# Is it possible to create notification after fetching data from webservice?

Tags: android, notifications

Am having doubt whether i can create notification after getting data from webservice need to create notification through Notification manager is it possible because i cannot see any working model on this i don't like in using in GCM or other push notification i need to create notification using notification mananger is it possible let me explain my problem more precisely whenver i get new data from webservice to sqlite i need to get notification how can i achieve this without push notification method ?

This is the webservice code where i fetch record from server in activity and saving it in sqlite:

```
       public class AccountLiast extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Accounts.this);

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Dialog.setMessage("Syncing Please Wait");
                Dialog.show();

            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());


                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], new JSONObject(),
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                String server_response = response.toString();
                                try {
                                    Model_Account modelobjs = new Model_Account();
                                    JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                                    JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("AccountPageLoadAccountListResult"));for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                        modelobjs.setCompany_group(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyGroup"));
                                        modelobjs.setParent_company(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                                        modelobjs.setState(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Region"));
                                        modelobjs.setAccountID(json_arrayJSONObject.getInt("AccountID"));
                                        modelobjs.setCompany_name(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
  //This is where i saving it in sqlite db                                    
  account_sf_db.InsertorUpdate(modelobjs);
                                        accountListAdapter.addModelClass(modelobjs);

                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void modleobjs) {
                super.onPostExecute(modleobjs);


                Dialog.hide();

            }
```

Comment: what do you want to show in notification

Answer (score 1):

- You can use built-in notification functionality

**Example**

```
public void generateNotification(String alertMessage) {
        Intent offlineIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
        offlineIntent.setAction("Go Offline");

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.logo);

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityHome.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


        PendingIntent mainPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(alertMessage)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(alarmSound).setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(mainPIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(m, noti);

    }
```

-- Here i am passing json response alertMessage in method. :

```
 generateNotification(String alertMessage)
```

Comment: first of all Thanks  NikPatel my primary doubt is can i use service for fetching data from webservice and notify or can i place built in notification method in activity itself

Comment: u can use built in notification method in activity itself. and u can pass json response in generateNotification Method

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create your notification after you get data from your webservice,

I assume you are getting this data at `Service`, so below you can find a small example that fetching data on `Service`

**Edit** I changed your `doInBackground` as your needs

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, params[0], new JSONObject(),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            String server_response = response.toString();
                            try {
                                Model_Account modelobjs = new Model_Account();
                                JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                                JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("AccountPageLoadAccountListResult"));for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    modelobjs.setCompany_group(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyGroup"));
                                    modelobjs.setParent_company(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                                    modelobjs.setState(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Region"));
                                    modelobjs.setAccountID(json_arrayJSONObject.getInt("AccountID"));
                                    modelobjs.setCompany_name(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                                    //This is where i saving it in sqlite db                                    
                                    account_sf_db.InsertorUpdate(modelobjs);
                                    showNotification(modelobjs); // This is where you will show your notification
                                    accountListAdapter.addModelClass(modelobjs);

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
            queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
            return null;
        }

private void showNotification (Model_Account modelobjs) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(modelobjs.getCompany_name());
                    .setContentText("This is notification message");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //put your activity here

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: am fetching and saving it in sqlite database as soon i fetched record from service need to notify how can i do this

Comment: Then how can i parse this

Comment: You need to show me your service , whre do you fetch codes and where do you adding your records to sqlite. Then I can help you better

Comment: Ok just use my showNotification method and call it below your account_sf_db.InsertorUpdate(modelobjs); this line it will show you notification. You can pass your modelobjs as parameter also. To make this you need to change constructor

Comment: constructor of which thing?

Comment: Thankz il give a try and let you know thank you so much Emin

Comment: How can i trigger service whenever network is available

Comment: This is a completely different question, please post a new question for this

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet illustrates a simple notification that specifies an activity to open when the user clicks the notification. Notice that the code creates a `TaskStackBuilder` object and uses it to create the `PendingIntent` for the action. This pattern is explained in more detail in the section Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
   TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
   //Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
   stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
   // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
 (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
 mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

this is an example of creating Simple notification put this snippet and customize where ever you need to show.

Read more about notification : [Notification | Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)